# Adding items into ObservableCollection is changing a backing field on the same ViewModel

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have been experimenting with Winui 3 and I have noticed an issue which I am not sure if it is of my own doing or if it some sort bug. I have a ViewModel which when navigated too, passes a Model object to the ViewModel which then pushes the Model data to the backing fields.

At the same time the ViewModel queries the database and runs it through a foreach and adds it to a ObservableCollection. What I have found, on the first foreach loop it is replacing the UsersID backing field value with the ID of the first item through the foreach loop.

```
public async void Initialize(object queryObject)
{
    Model = (InspectionModel)queryObject;
    var users = await Task.Run(App.Repository.Users.GetCertifiersAsync);

    foreach (var item in users)
    {
        Certifiers.Add(item);
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<UsersModel> Certifiers = new ObservableCollection<UsersModel>();

public int UsersID
{
    get { return Model.UsersID; }
    set
    {
        Model.UsersID = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UsersID));
        IsModified = true;
    }
}
```

`Certifiers` is the `ItemsSource` for a combobox and `UsersID` is the `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Do you clear `Certifiers` before you add the new items?

Comment: @mm8 I just tried it with `Certifiers.Clear();` but it didnt make a difference. When I step through the code `UsersID` gets set to what it should be when the `Model = (InspectionModel)queryObject;` line is hit and it stays the right value until the first loop of the foreach loop has finished.

Comment: Please share the code of InspectionModel.